# What are the alternatives for 'continue' and 'break'? in C

Tags: c, loops

```
#include <stdio.h>

int c, i, n, digit_cnt = 0, cnt = 0, total = 0;

int main(void)
{
    while (c = getchar())
    {
        if (c == 'E')
            break;
        ++cnt;
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++digit_cnt;
    }

    i = -5;
    n = 50;
    while (i < n)
    {
        ++i;
        if (i == 0)
            continue;
        total += i;
        printf("i = %d and total = %d\n", i, total);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to avoid using breaks and continues, what are some ways to make these two pieces of codes work the same without using any breaks and continues?

Comment: Depending on context, `return` and `goto` (and sometimes `longjmp()` if you've made an appropriate call to `setjmp()`).  Using `goto` is the ubiquitous, always available, alternative, but is often regarded as anathema (certainly in comparison with `break` and `continue`).  See also [GOTO: Still considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46586/15168)

Comment: I'm curious: Why do you want to avoid break and continue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid `break` and `continue` statements here, rethink the logic of your code.

Instead of testing for `E` inside the loop and using `break`, test in the controlling expression for the `while` statement. Note also that `getchar()` can return `EOF`; an input failure causes `getchar()` to return `EOF` on subsequent calls, and this would lead the posted code to an infinite loop. You might want to handle `EOF` after the loop if that is the cause of the exit.

```
while ((c = getchar()) != 'E' && c != EOF)
    {
        ++cnt;
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++digit_cnt;
    }
```

Instead of checking to see if `i == 0` and then using `continue`, check to see if `i != 0` and then do something:

```
    if (i != 0) {
        total += i;
        printf("i = %d and total = %d\n", i, total);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
int main(void)
{
    while ((c = getchar()) != 'E')
    {
        ++cnt;
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++digit_cnt;
    }

    i = -5;
    n = 50;
    while (i < n)
    {
        ++i;
        if (i != 0)
        {
            total += i;
            printf("i = %d and total = %d\n", i, total);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```